# Editable List in Preferences

Tags: android, list, preferences, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to add an editable List to a preference screen? The user should be able to add and remove entries from the list.
Or do I have to make a separate screen and save it into the preferences manually?

**Edit:**

```
    <PreferenceScreen
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory android:summary="@string/MasterDeviceDescription" android:title="@string/MasterDeviceCat">
            <EditTextPreference android:key="@string/MasterIP" android:title="@string/MasterIPLabel"></EditTextPreference>
            <CheckBoxPreference android:key="@string/ManualDevice" android:title="@string/ManualDeviceLabel"></CheckBoxPreference>
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/ManualDeviceCat" android:summary="@string/ManualDeviceDescription">
            <!-- HERE -->
        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

It should be used from a preference screen which is called from a menu.

**Edit 2**

I have to use it to get an optional list of user-created data for use by the application.

Comment: can you elaborate where you want to use it?

Comment: I also need this. Too bad it doesn't exist ready to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any default control.